# Policy query execution

Tags: php, mysql

When I insert a new record in the users table, first check email and nickname were not already added. There is a possibility that another user who registers with the same data simultaneously me false result? To clarify:

**Connect 1:**

```
 > SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = 'test';
```

*Empty set (0.00 sec)*

**Connect 2:**

```
> SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = 'test';
```

*Empty set (0.00 sec)*

```
> INSERT INTO account(username) VALUES ('test');
```

*Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)*

**Connect 1:**

```
> INSERT INTO account(username) VALUES ('test');
```

*Error. Duplicate key*

What I want to know is if MySQL works this way, by running queries when they come, and best practices to use.
I noticed that during a transition, the changes made ​​by other connections are not visible. Why? You can use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE outside the transitions? The massive use of foreign key to ensure data integrity is a recommended practice?

**edit:**
Put another way. Ignore the stupid example. I want the next user who registers has an age greater than all those already

```
> SELECT MAX (age) FROM account;
```

[... Check if a user's age is higher ...]

```
> INSERT INTO accounts (age) VALUES ('$ var');
```

How do I make sure that there is a risk to have two users with the same field camp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice in this case would be to create `UNIQUE` constraint (`UNIQUE INDEX`).

When you get 2 queries simultaneously you'll get 1 query failed and be able to handle it with proper message to user.

Comment: @ypercube: yes, and it is a best practice anyway ))

Answer (score 0):

Gheez listing all the best practices for MySQL would require a book.

Let me first answer:

> I want the next user who registers has an age greater than all those already

**Use a trigger:**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bi_account_each BEFORE INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  declare MaxAge integer;

  SELECT Max(account.age) INTO MaxAge FROM account;
  IF (new.age <= MaxAge) THEN BEGIN
    /* force an error by selecting from a table_that_does_not_exist.*/
    SELECT * FROM 
      ErrFromTrigger_bi_account_each_New_Member_Must_Be_Older_then_The_Last
  END; END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Or a stored function**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION CanInsertInAccount(pAge integer) RETURNS boolean
BEGIN
  declare MaxAge integer;
  declare InsertAllowed boolean;

  SELECT Max(account.age) INTO MaxAge FROM account;
  SET InsertAllowed = (pAge > MaxAge);

  RETURN InsertAllowed;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html
For more info on triggers.
And: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html
For more info on stored procedures and functions.

As for **best practices**, my list would be:

1. **Don't trust customer input:** When inserting values from php into MySQL always use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on **every** value (or use PDO {prepared statements}); This will protect you from SQL-injection attacks.
2. **Strip HTML tags before displaying customer inputted data** Disallow all HTML. Use htmlspecialchars() to convert HTML characters into HTML entities. So characters like < and > that mark the beginning/end of a tag are turned into < and >. It is not enough to simply use strip_tags() to only allow some tags as the function does not strip out harmful attributes like the onclick or onload.
3. Normalize your database
4. Use foreign key checks
5. Use transactions, but commit (or rollback) as often as you can. Only put stuff that belongs together in one transaction.
6. Use triggers
7. Use stored procedures to manipulate and test stuff that depends on the layout of your database.

That's what I can think of right now, the list is by no means complete and these things are somewhat personal. It works for me, YMMV.